# Two switching power supplies on one board

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I want to put two TPS63050 buck-boost regulators on the same board to provide a clean 5V and 3.3V respectively from the same source voltage in the 4-5V range. Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of in doing that? I've used one TPS63050 successfully before.

I also was thinking I can wire the power good output from each of them together for a single power good output. Good plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your chips will work. If you lock the chips in antiphase there will be better EMC due to some input ripple cancel. There is a pitfall that really did happen with 3 chips close together on a common 48 VDC input supply with bobbin core inductors laid out close together. Yes there was interaction due to stray magnetic coupling which had to be managed. So don't go too close and use coils that have low stray fields.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean by lock the chips in antiphase.

Comment: @ Hari .You could drive both chips with an external clock that has Q and not Q outputs .Most chips tell you how do do this .When you look at each chip on channel 1 and 2 of your scope you will see both traces stationary when you are locked .The EMC gain is worth it.

Comment: I could not find anything in this particular chip's datasheet about locking two chips, it doesn't seem to have any inputs that could serve that purpose.

Comment: @pipe .well maybe the chips osc is not accessable .When the RC osc is on a pin then it is easy .I avoid  unlockable chips.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at some of TIs PMIC chips. There are multiple devices that can operate as two switching voltage regulators in one controller package. This may very well save you some on silicon cost.

You may also want to consider starting with a higher input voltage so that your switchers can be operating in buck mode all the time. This would lead to a somewhat simpler circuit design and eliminate the need to deal with buck/boost mode switchover compensation which does lead to more design risk.

Comment: A saggy USB output is what I'm coping with as input